# What's the difference between 'group' and 'grouping'?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I'm not a native English speaker and I was wondering the difference between those two terms.

From what I understood so far 'group' is a generic word used to denote a number of persons/things considered related in some way.
'grouping' is used to denote a group of people sharing a common intent or interest.

Is this the case? It seems that 'grouping' has a more specific meaning and that 'group' can be  used always in place of 'grouping' (because it's a more general term).

So in which case do you use 'group' and in which one do you use 'grouping' instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the word `group` your emphasis should be on the collection of things in the group.

*How many people do you have in your group?*

When you use the word `grouping` your emphasis should be on the act of forming the group rather than the group itself.

*Which grouping would be better- girls in one group and guys in another, or else adults vs children?*

Comment: +1 for good example of a (fairly unusual) context where *grouping* is actually to be preferred. In cases where it's not so clear-cut as this, the generic advice should be to always use *group*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the thing that is confusing, is that "group" can be both a noun and a verb, and "grouping" likewise.

"Group" as a noun means the collection of things.
"Grouping" as a noun, is a gerund. A [Gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund), in English is :**"As applied to English, it refers to the usage of a verb (in its -ing form) as a noun."**
So, it's a verb being used as a noun! Maybe that's what's confusing you?

There is no difference in meaning whatsoever between these two nouns. The only difference, is their *usage*. That is, there are situations where one would use "group", but not "grouping" E.g.:

> The group of people gradually grew in size.
>   I don't like the grouping system we have at work....

We cannot say, "I don't like the group system..." It's grammatically incorrect.

"Group" as a verb is to arrange into a group. To form a collection of people or items.
"Grouping" as a verb is the act of arranging the group *in present time*, E.g.:  "I am grouping these letters together." Instead of "I am group..."

I hope that clears up any ambiguity.